# restrictive "which" vs. non-restrictive "that"

Tags: conjunctions

Can you, please, explain why in one sentence below the word "which" is used and in another one, "that"? Why not "that" in both? Or why not "which" in both?

> At that time, humans did not yet know that the earth was round, a fact
> **which** is now known to every schoolchild.
>
> What’s really funny, the new ones were twins, a fact **that** none of us
> realized right away.

(In my first language the same word is used for translating either of these two words, so I don't see the difference.)

Comment: I'll keep saying this: the distinction between that and which is a pure invention of grammarians and is not respected by any English speaker, even the most careful.

Comment: Use *which* when choosing between a list of items, or referring to human beings. Otherwise, use *that*.

Comment: @FeliniusRex - So, are you saying that the first sentence would sound okay with "that" instead of "which" ("_At that time, humans did not yet know that the earth was round, a fact **that** is now known to every schoolchild_")?

Comment: @brilliant Yes, at least in AmE; this may be a British/American difference, though.

Comment: @FeliniusRex - I see. thank you.